# git merge origin origin/master - Interpretation

Tags: git, merge

What does

> git merge origin origin/master

mean? It looks to me like were merging a remote repository with a branch on the remote repository. Here, origin is the remote repository and origin/master is the master branch on the remote repository. So what two branches are being merged? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

All parameters to 'git merge' in this case are branches that you're merging from, i.e. source branches. You're always merging *to* the current branch.

Because `origin` is a remote name, git automatically expands it to that remote's *default branch*, so it's actually equivalent to `origin/master` – the command is being told to merge the same branch twice.

(It *is* possible to merge more than one branch, known as "octopus merge", but this is rarely done – and when it is done, the branches of course are different.)

As it is, the command doesn't make much sense. Maybe it should have been either `git merge origin/master` (without the duplication) or `git pull origin master`.

Comment: Thanks grawity! That makes sense, but you're right, doesn't make sense to mere two of the same branches together. For some context, here is where I saw the command (see the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272685/11535048